# Processing/Java - Simple example

Tags: java, command-line, processing

I'm trying to get a simple example to run. The below code compiles but gives me errors when I try to run it.  I'm a newbie to Processing/Java.  Also, my goal is to see if I can make a simple command line utility with processing for charting/graphics (very simple), kind of like gnuplot.

```
import processing.core.*;

public class MyProcessingSketch extends PApplet {

  public void setup() {
    size(200,200);
    background(0);
  }

  public void draw() {
    stroke(255);
    if (mousePressed) {
      line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main(new String[] { "--present", "MyProcessingSketch" });
  }
}
```

I build with

```
javac -cp location/of/core/core.jar MyProcessingSketch.java
```

and run with

```
java -cp location/of/core/core.jar MyProcessingSketch
```

the error I get is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyProcessingSketch
```

EDIT:

I've now tried

```
java -cp "location/of/core/core.jar:." MyProcessingSketch
```

and the error is now,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You're trying to run an applet as a desktop application.  At best it should be loaded into a browser, at worse, you can try using the applet viewer included with the JDK

Comment: *"I'm a newbie to Processing..."*  Why are you bothering with that primitive AWT based API?

Comment: As an aside, what is the `--present` attribute? I don't see it [mentioned in the JavaDocs](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#main%28java.lang.String[]%29).

Comment: It was part of a simple example that works with eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You have set your classpath to `location/of/core/core.jar`, but that doesn't include the current directory where your class lies.

Include "." (the current directory) in your classpath option:

```
java -cp "location/of/core/core.jar:." MyProcessingSketch
```

The ":" is the path separator on Unix and Linux; use a semicolon on Windows instead.

```
java -cp "location/of/core/core.jar;." MyProcessingSketch
```

Comment: @ctsa It is also a good idea to put your class in a package.  Then you would run `mypackage.MyProcessingSketch`

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath currently only contains `location/of/core/core.jar`, and not `MyProcessingSketch.class`. You should do 
`java -cp location/of/core/core.jar;. MyProcessingSketch` to include the current directory.